# Expected array when calling function

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to learn a little VBA an I'm in the process of saving ranges as CSV files.

However, I'm having trouble with this line of code

```
Call SaveRangeAsCSV(SelectDown("B5:D5"), "C:\Test\test.csv", True)
```

And here is a snippet of the SelectDown function.

```
Private Function SelectDown(Range As String) As Range
    SelectDown = Range(Range, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Select 
End Function
```

I get the error: Expected array. I cannot seem to understand what the problem is. Any help would be appreciated :-)

Comment: change `Range As String` to `RangeAddress As String` and `SelectDown = Range(Range, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Select` to `Set SelectDown = Range(RangeAddress, ActiveCell.End(xlDown))`

Comment: So far so good, that cleared up the expected array, now I get a Runtime Error 424: object required instead

Comment: have you removed `.Select` keyword in line `...ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Select`?

Comment: Ah, there was the answer, thank you very much ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the function SaveRangeAsCSV is expecting an array, but you are passing in a Range.  This function is not a built-in Excel function, so I can't check it.  Maybe you could check what arguments it is expecting?

Comment: Problem is that it's the first argument of that function call that fails, so it's the SelectDown function, and not SaveRangeAsCSV :-)

Answer (score 0):

My function now looks like this and is working perfectly.

```
Private Function SelectDown(RangeAddress As String) As Range
    Set SelectDown = Range(RangeAddress, ActiveCell.End(xlDown))
End Function
```

Comment: two posts may be helpful for you: [How to avoid using Select/Active statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select) and [How to determine last used row/column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba/11169920#11169920). Using `xlDown` is unreliable in some cases